# Versioning my atom plugins

Tags: atom-editor

I'm a Vim user who's recently discovered Atom and I think it's great.  One thing that it seems to be missing is the ability to version *which* plugins I have installed, such that if I were to install Atom on a new machine, I would pull down some hypothetical configuration file and it would know to install all my plugins.

Using VIM and a plugin manager, this would typically just be stored in the vim config.  Does this already exist in Atom and I'm just missing something?

Comment: I don't know if such a thing exists or not, but when setting up a new machine, I normally just copy over my .atom directory to get all of that.

Comment: You can ‘star’ packages, and then run `apm starred --install`.

Comment: Being able to install all starred plugins sounds pretty cool, but I'm not sure I can get over not being able to version these things myself.

Answer (score 2):

You can try using *atom package manager* (**apm**) :

First export the list of your plugins in a file

```
 apm list --installed --bare > packages.list
```

The file will look like this :

```
atom-beautify@0.28.21
atom-ternjs@0.13.2
color-picker@2.1.1
...
```

Then when you are on a new machine, just install Atom and run

```
 apm install --packages-file packages.list
```

Otherwise you can also try to look into this plugin : https://atom.io/packages/sync-settings